# Accessing NSDocumentDirectory on iPad Simulator

Tags: objective-c, simulator, nsdocumentdirectory

I've added a very simple .csv file to my app's NSDocumentDirectory using:

```
-(IBAction)exportModule:(id)sender{
    NSString *fileName = @"exportedfile.csv";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSString *exportString = @"I've,been,exported";
    NSData *testData=[exportString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *docDir = documentsDirectory;
    NSString *completePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [testData writeToFile:completePath atomically:YES];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:completePath]) {
    NSLog(@"Theres a file here!");
    }

}
```

The  app gets into the if statement printing `"Theres a file here!"`, however I would like open the file and see if there were any problems in formatting the .csv.

If I were running on a physical device, I'd be able to open it up in iTunes and take a look there, but is there a way to examine the .csv while only using the simulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this at the beginning of all of my programs for using the simulator

```
NSLog(@"Documents: %@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: Just to add to the answer. This print out will show you the directory your documents lives on your Harddrive. You can open this up in the finder and view your files.

Comment: Thanks @MarkPowell, perhaps I was a bit terse :)

Comment: It is better to use 'lastObject' for one object in a array to prevent array index out of bounds exceptions.